# SWT Table, adding items from a thread hangs

Tags: multithreading, swt

I have a GUI with a table - that table is populated by the contents of an InputStreamReader. In order to do this, I am creating a thread that monitors the InputStream, and when there is a new line to read, it adds it to table. The problem I am running into is that the creation of the thread seems to hang the entire application.  What is the typical way of going about doing this?

The flow goes:

Gui->Button onUp->LogCatController.start-> gui.getDisplay().asyncExec(AdbThreadReader)->addLine

```
public class Gui {

    protected Shell shell;
    private Display display;
    private Table logCatTable;
    private Text text;

    private LogCatController logCatController;
    private TableColumn tblclmnDate;


    public void open() {
        this.display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        ...

        logCatTable = new Table(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
        FormData fd_logCatTable = new FormData();
        fd_logCatTable.left = new FormAttachment(0, 142);
        fd_logCatTable.right = new FormAttachment(100);
        fd_logCatTable.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
        fd_logCatTable.top = new FormAttachment(0);
        logCatTable.setLayoutData(fd_logCatTable);
        logCatTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
        logCatTable.setLinesVisible(true);

        ...

        Button btnStart = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        btnStart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    logCatController.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    public Table getLogCatTable() {
        return logCatTable;
    }
    public Display getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

}


public class LogCatController {
    private DataBindingContext m_bindingContext;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdbLine.class);

    private LogCat logcat;
    private Gui gui;

    public LogCatController(Gui gui){
        this.gui = gui;
        logcat = new LogCat();
        m_bindingContext = initDataBindings();
    }

    public void start() throws IOException{
        logcat.execute();
        BufferedReader read = logcat.getSTDOUT();
        BufferedReader error = logcat.getSTDERR();

        Runnable readRunnable = new AdbLineReaderThread(read);
        gui.getDisplay().asyncExec(readRunnable);
    }
private void addLine(AdbLine l){
    logger.debug("Adding: " + l);
    Table logCatTable = this.gui.getLogCatTable();
    TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(logCatTable, SWT.NONE);
    tableItem.setText(new String[] {"time", l.getLevel().toString(), String.valueOf(l.getPid()), l.getMessage()});
    tableItem.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
}

public class AdbLineReaderThread implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader read;
    public AdbLineReaderThread(BufferedReader read){
        this.read = read;
    }

    public void run() {
        logger.debug("AdbLinReaderThread run");
        String line = null;
        try{
            while( (line = read.readLine()) != null){
                logger.debug(line);
                AdbLine l = new AdbLine(line);
                addLine(l);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not parse: " + line);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}


public class LogCat extends BackgroundCommand{

    public LogCat(){
        super(...);     
    }               
}
```

Comment: Your addLine() call should be wrapped in Display.asyncExec() and AdbLineReaderThread shouldn't be run in Display.asyncExec() as you want everything to happen off the SWT thread and only GUI updates to happen on SWT Thread.

Answer (score 1):

All manipulation of SWT objects must happen in the SWT event thread. To insure this enclose the "meat" of addLine in

```
logCatTable.getDisplay.syncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use `asyncExec(...)` if you don't need to wait for the result and don't have any concurrency issues with `AdbLine`...

Comment: Yes, you can see in the start() method, I am running: "gui.getDisplay().asyncExec(readRunnable);" is this not correct?

Comment: @wuntee: No, it's not.  You're running your readRunnable on the UI thread.  This is why you see your thread "hanging".  You're asking SWT to run it on the UI, and it's starving the UI's dispatch loop.  So your UI is hung.  You want to run it on a background thread and then use nonty's advice to exec the updates on the UI thread.

Comment: So, would I need to create a new class with some sort of buffer to pass information from the updateThread (ran via asyncExec) and the backgroundThread?  also, if this is constantly updating, how do I not starve the UI thread? Do I have to "schedule" the asyncExec every so often?  the whole use case is that I am monitoring an InputStreamReader of a Runtime.exec command that never terminates, and adding the output to the Table...

Comment: The other problem is that if I dont run readRunnable on the UI thread, it will throw an exception because readRunnable is trying to directly insert rows into the table...